# Парсер не выводит заголовок статьи

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://stopgame.ru/news'
HEADERS = {'Тут что-то было.'}

def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('a', class_='caption caption-bold')
    print(items)

def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)    
    print(html)
    get_content(html.text)


parse()
```

Я делаю парсер stopgame, но при поиске класса `'caption caption-bold'` консоль выдает вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Браузер (class):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы ищите тег `a` с `class` = `"caption caption-bold"`, а тот класс у `div`, как видно по скриншоту

---

Вариант парсера через css-селектор:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

rs = requests.get('https://stopgame.ru/news')
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

for x in root.select('.article-summary .caption'):
    print(x.get_text(strip=True))
```